# SQLAlchemy query after call store procedure

Tags: python, mysql, session, sqlalchemy

I have a MySQL stored procedure that updates some rows in a table. After I call that SP I need consult throw session.query.... but the session is not refreshed.
My connection is:

```py
db_setup = 'mysql+pymysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}?charset=utf8'.format(
    os.environ.get("USERNAME"),
    os.environ.get("PASSWORD"),
    os.environ.get("HOST"),
    os.environ.get("PORT"),
    os.environ.get("DATABASE")
)

engine = create_engine(db_setup, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=True, autoflush=False)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()
```

The call to SP:

```
connection = engine.raw_connection()
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('nameSP',[1])
    result = list(cursor.fetchall())
    cursor.close()
    connection.commit()
except Exception as e:
    raise InternalServerError(e)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Finally, I try to execute query `session.query(Table).filter()` and the result is not updated, but in the DB is OK, then I restart the application and the information is updated.
Also, I tried to add `session.expire_all()` after executing SP and it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Likely you are creating a session at the module level when you should be creating the session when you actually want to make the query.

Comment: Hi @univerio, I've created the sessionmaker globally and I use the session in every module that I need it.

Comment: You are creating a *single* session over the lifetime of your entire application when you should create a new session every single time you want to access the database. This is based on the code that you've given, of course, but since what you've provided is incomplete, I'm making a guess based on the fact that `Session` and `session` are created at the same level.